# Why is Debian unable to locate package openjdk-16-jre-headless?

Tags: debian, package-management, java

I am using Debian 10.6.

```
$ sudo apt install openjdk-16-jre-headless
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-16-jre-headless
```

Here is my package list. Notice how there is only openjdk 11, and nothing else.

```
$ apt search openjdk
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
default-jdk/oldstable 2:1.11-71 i386
  Standard Java or Java compatible Development Kit

default-jdk-doc/oldstable 2:1.11-71 amd64
  Standard Java or Java compatible Development Kit (documentation)

default-jdk-headless/oldstable,now 2:1.11-71 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Standard Java or Java compatible Development Kit (headless)

default-jre/oldstable,now 2:1.11-71 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Standard Java or Java compatible Runtime

default-jre-headless/oldstable,now 2:1.11-71 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Standard Java or Java compatible Runtime (headless)

java-package/oldstable,oldstable 0.62 all
  Utility for creating Java Debian packages

jtreg/oldstable,oldstable 4.2-b14-1 all
  Regression Test Harness for the OpenJDK platform

libhsdis0-fcml/oldstable 1.1.3-3 amd64
  HotSpot disassembler plugin using FCML

libreoffice/oldstable 1:6.1.5-3+deb10u7 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:6.1.5-3+deb10u6]
  office productivity suite (metapackage)

nvidia-openjdk-8-jre/oldstable 9.+8u77~9.2.148-7+deb10u1 amd64
  NVIDIA provided OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT

openjdk-11-dbg/oldstable 11.0.13+8-1~deb10u1 amd64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt` can’t locate `openjdk-16-jre-headless` because [the OpenJDK 16 packages](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/openjdk-16) aren’t available in any Debian release.

The only release available to you in Debian 10 is [OpenJDK 11](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/openjdk-11). Debian 11 has [OpenJDK 17](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/openjdk-17). Both of these are releases with long-term support.

Answer (score 1):

`openjdk-16-jre-headless` isn't packaged on Debian. You have to use [`openjdk-11-jre-headless`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/openjdk-11-jre-headless), it can be installed after enabling the security repository.

[Java and debian.](https://wiki.debian.org/Java#Java_and_Debian)